# Make a hyperlink to compose a new email with the receive's email is specified

Tags: c#, xaml, email

Hi I'm developing a UWP application with C# and XAML and in the about page I want to have a hyperlink with its content set to "Feedback" and whenever the users click on it, I want it to open their mail app or open the browser and opening they're email account to compose me a message with my email in the To textbox!
What NavigateUri should I write to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like you want mailto for link. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you achieve this by `mailto:theEmail@dresse.toWriteTo`.

Atleast that is the URL hyperlinks like that actually show.